# Retrieve an element by id in array in HTML (angular.js)

Tags: angularjs

Output should be

```
Name : AAA, Type: Flower
Name : BBB, Type: Bird
```

Controller

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {id: 0, name: 'AAA', type: 12},
    {id: 1, name: 'BBB', type: 33}];

  $scope.types = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Dog'},
    {id: 12, name: 'Flower'},
    {id: 24, name: 'Fish'},
    {id: 33, name: 'Bird'}];
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
          Name : {{ item.name }}, Type: {{ ??? }}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I retrieve a matching element in $scope.types by 'item.type'?

Comment: I have updated jsfiddle please check

Comment: I edited the code to make it more specific. Id is not sequential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller should be:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {id: 0, name: 'AAA', type: 12},
    {id: 1, name: 'BBB', type: 33}];

  $scope.types = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Dog'},
    {id: 12, name: 'Flower'},
    {id: 24, name: 'Fish'},
    {id: 33, name: 'Bird'}];
  $scope.getType = function(id){
    return $scope.types.filter(function(item){
      return (item.id === id);
    })[0].name;
  }
}
```

And template:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
          Name : {{ item.name }}, Type: {{ getType(item.type) }}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I worked here: http://jsfiddle.net/f9019o5k/2/

Comment: Exact same answer has been voted -ve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429798/retrieve-an-element-by-id-in-array-in-html-angular-js#answer-33429825

Comment: it got the idea from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write and function in your controller which will return the required type. Doing entire thing in HTML might make it unreadable and complex

```
$scope.getType(id){
    return $scope.items.filter(function(item){
        item.id === id;
    });
}
```

And call it in your HTML as

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
          Name : {{ item.name }}, Type: {{ getType(item.id) }}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its too simple if we Use angular filters to achieve this.

```
app.filter('myFilter ', function() {
  return function(input,obj) {
    angular.forEach(obj,function(val){
        if(val.id ==  input)
        {
           return val.name;
        }
     })
  };
});
```

**Html**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
     Name : {{ item.name }}, Type: {{ item.type | myFilter:types   }} 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```